# SQLITE Access denied error in Laravel

Tags: laravel, sqlite

I am using sqlite as my default database driver.
I already connected the database using .env and also seeded some data using tinker.
N.B: Data is inserted correctly in my database. Database name is

> database.sqlite

But when I try to login using email and password created with tinker it shows the following error.

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = ryleigh12@example.net limit 1)
```

[here is the image showing that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvLaX.png)

Comment: comment out the DB_* config values in your .env, the only config value you need is `DB_CONNECTION=sqlite`

Comment: Your database connection error

Comment: @xanadev did what you asked still same error

Comment: @SachinAghera if there was problem in connecting database how did the migration and seed operations were ok?

Comment: Have you check you phpmyadmin working with provided credential? or either you forgot to create you datatabse.

Comment: @SachinAghera Have you not been reading what I said earlier?

Comment: access denied means you provided credentials to access the database, but those credentials are invalid, the problem is .env is configured to work with mysql by default, which is why the .env file contains **DB_USERNAME** and **DB_PASSWORD** how did you comment out .env DB_* keys

Comment: @xanadev I just simple removed them. only 
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite is remained

Comment: i had the same problem working with sqlite, when i commented out the other config keys, everything worked as it should.

Comment: that's my question I am even using username, passwords. by still showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the PHP's default web server (php artisan serve) you need to restart your server after any change in your .env file.

Comment: tried that several times. question is pretty old. So I am not using sqlite anymore :)